# NameError. Might be eval(), raw_input, or misunderstanding

Tags: python, eval

Working with Python 2.6 and receiving an annoying error, and I'm still unsure why. My file of interest contains multiple lines of only a single value. I want to retrieve these values. This snippet of code

```
f = open(file, 'r')
for line in file:
    value = eval(line)
```

results in the following error message:

```
   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'c' is not defined
```

So I researched  here on Stack Overflow.. with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309843/calling-class-from-an-external-module-causes-nameerror-in-idle-it-works-fine) question and [another](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7747871/revisions) one.. but I'm having trouble drawing connections between their problems and mine. What I got from them is that my use of `eval()` may be confusing Python and I should use `raw_input` to let Python know that it doesn't have to evaluate `line` but rather the actual variables `line` represents. However, fixing my code to be:

```
for line in file:
    value = eval(raw_input(line))
```

Which kicked out the following error (and may have overloaded terminal.. it simply froze up until I quit the program):

```
File "<string>", line 0
^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

What am I doing wrong here? I've picked up the fact that `eval()` isn't the favorite to use around SO, am I misunderstanding it's function?
EDIT: My file is a list of values so,

```
2 
3
2
3
1
0
```

etc

*EDIT* So it was a **misunderstanding**. Thank you to DSM for pointing out my file names being mismatched and to Levon for still helping out and showing `int` as a better alternative to `eval`.

Comment: How exactly should we help you without knowing what's in your file?

Comment: If you want to read data from a file that contains python expressions consinder using [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

Comment: I added the file, sorry to be confusing, it's a very basic file. Also.. there is no 'c' in it.. which is confusing me to no end.

Comment: @AllysonKim: your edited post is still looping over the characters in `file`; you need to loop over `f`.

Comment: @DSM perfect.. sheesh, that's annoying. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to read those numbers from a file and convert them to integers this will do.

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        value = int(line)
```

Then you can use the value as needed.

*Aside*: The advantage of using `with` to open the file is that it is automatically closed for you when you are done, or an exception is encountered.

Comment: I think I resolved my original problem, but is there a reason to use `int` instead of `eval`?

Comment: @AllysonKim -- Yes.  with `eval`, it's possible for someone to have your program run arbitrary code -- which makes your program a security liability.  Even if you're the only one running your program, it's a bad habit to have.

Comment: Is there any reason to use `eval`? `eval` will execute any Python code and that may be a big Big BIG security hole for your application.

Comment: @AllysonKim Also to just add what mgilson said, using `int` makes your intention clear.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the help. I realize it was a very silly mistake in the first place, but I'll never learn without people like you helping me out. `int` it is.

Comment: @AllysonKim You are welcome .. and guess what .. *no one* around here was born with this knowledge, we all had to learn it at some time or other :)

Comment: @matthias, there was no specific reason to use `eval()`, a programmer wrote it in while editing my code (I suppose that I will seek other sources for help now).

Comment: @Levon I appreciate the encouragement :)

Answer (score 0):

To respond to the title of your question, yes you are misunderstanding it. Let me explain:
eval executes the code you place in it. So `x=eval('c')` is the same as `x=c`.
`raw_input` is used to get user input. The parameter is the string to display to the user, not the input.
If you just want to read the values that are in a file, you could use

```
with open('file') as f:
    for line in f:
        var = int(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to retrieve values from the files then this will do, using `eval()` for this doesn't make sense:

```
>>> with open('data.txt') as f:
        values=[int(x) for x in f]


>>> values
[2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 0]
```